# Variable values in function called are not updated

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the total pay and the pay rate but it seems the hour in pay_rate function is not updated when the function called is used which minus 40 then minus 4.
Please support me on this.
This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
void pay_rate(float, float*);
void total_pay(float, float, float*);
int main() {
  float h, rate, total_salary = 0;
  printf("Input worked hours: ");
  scanf("%f", &h);
  pay_rate(h, &rate);
  // printf("%f", rate);
  total_pay(h ,rate,&total_salary);
  // printf("\n%f", total_salary);
  
}

void pay_rate(float hour, float* rate) {
  float temp = 0;
  if (0 < hour && hour <= 40)
  {
    temp = hour-40;
    *rate = 12.5;
    printf("\n%f", temp);
  } else if (0 < temp && temp <= 4) {
    *rate = 15;
    temp = temp-4;
    printf("\n%f", temp);
  } else if (temp > 0) {
    *rate = 20;
    printf("\n%f",temp);
  }
}

void total_pay(float hours, float rate, float* salary){
  *salary = rate * hours;
  
}
```

I tried a temp variable but it wont work either.

Comment: In c++ prefer to pass by reference instead of passing by pointer. Your code looks like you are writing `c` with a `c++` compiler.

Comment: even better, return a value, not void

Comment: rate is initialized in main function already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be updated in another function you need to pass its address.

```
#include <iostream>
void pay_rate(float*, float*);
void total_pay(float, float, float*);
int main() {
  float h, rate, total_salary = 0;
  printf("Input worked hours: ");
  scanf("%f", &h);
  pay_rate(&h, &rate);
  // printf("%f", rate);
  total_pay(h ,rate,&total_salary);
  // printf("\n%f", total_salary);
  
}

void pay_rate(float* hour, float* rate) {
  float temp = *hour;
  if (0 < *hour && *hour <= 40)
  {
    temp = (*hour)-40;
    *rate = 12.5;
    printf("\n%f", temp);
  } else if (0 < temp && temp <= 4) {
    *rate = 15;
    temp = temp-4;
    printf("\n%f", temp);
  } else if (temp > 0) {
    *rate = 20;
    printf("\n%f",temp);
  }
  *hour = temp;
}

void total_pay(float hours, float rate, float* salary){
  *salary = rate * hours;
  
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I tried your approach and the console wont show any value for the temp.

Comment: @Woody Code has been fixed and updated in the answer.

Comment: @jonhLegend it still does not work btw

Comment: @Woody could you clarify what doesnt work?

Comment: i mean the console, when i print the value of temp, the console wont give me the value of temp.

Comment: Thats an issue with your IDE. the code you posted originally prints out the value of temp just fine. not a code issue.